# How to determine whether something is in a conditional statement in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, conditional-statements, php-parser

I have a copy of a PHP website and there are a lot of pages and a lot of code there. It uses conditional statements to determine what contents should be printed very much. Here's an example(there may be a lot of snippets like the one below):

```
<?php if($countryA): ?>
     <div myattr="myvalue">
<?php elseif($countryB): ?>
     <div myattr="myvalue">
<?php elseif($countryC): ?>
     <div myattr="myvalue">
<?php elseif($countryD): ?>
     <div myattr="myvalue">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Let's say, I don't care what it is in countryA,countryB and countryD, I only care if there is `<div myattr="myvalue">` in countryC.
If I want know how many times `<div myattr="myvalue">"` will occur if `$countryD` is `true`, I need to perform a search among all the files in my website directory using keyword `<div myattr="myvalue">` and check if there is `<?php elseif($countryC): ?>` in the context for *every* search result, which is really a huge burden...

Are there any ways to help me solve this problem efficiently? Do I need a PHP parser if I want to do this programmatically?

Comment: In general, you'd need a PHP parser to ascertain the 'scope' of any given conditional. But if the particular code you're dealing with is more constrained (e.g., if each if-country chunk is as simple as in your example), then you can get away with a simpler solution. So: how simple/general is the block following any given condition of interest?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty general, the block won't be as easy as I posted here, actually, it may contain hundreds lines of code...Looks like I really need a PHP parser.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need a parser or in other words , you have to save the format of your code or controls flow in a file or database and apply logic according to that saved data or flow.
I hope you get the sense.

Comment: Thx, do you know if there are any parsers that can simply tell me if a statement is in the block of a condition or not?

Comment: I know about a php function php_check_syntax but haven't used that.
Check if that is of any use for u.

Comment: it seems it's used for checking syntax errors, so it won't work for me. Thx all the same~

Comment: Check if this link helps.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions